# DataTable that can be accessed from Repeater.ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.Net, C#, and OOP in general, and I'm trying to get into the right paradigm about classes, objects, methods, etc.

I would like to access a `DataTable` from the Repeater.ItemDataBound event. Where would I create the `DataTable` so the method can access it? I don't want the DataTable created everytime ItemDataBound is called, just once. Would that be a separate class, or another method in the same class, or something else?

I want to use this to set values on controls in the `HeaderTemplate` of a `Repeater`. Here is my code:

```
public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numPages = 3, numItems = 10;

        int[] parentRepeatCnt = Enumerable.Range(0, numPages).ToArray();
        int[] childRepeatCnt = Enumerable.Range(0, numItems).ToArray();

        ParentRepeater.DataSource = parentRepeatCnt;
        ParentRepeater.DataBind();

        foreach (int i in parentRepeatCnt)
        {
            Repeater ChildRepeater = ParentRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("ChildRepeater") as Repeater;
            ChildRepeater.DataSource = childRepeatCnt;
            ChildRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public void ChildRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            Label Label1 = e.Item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            // access DataTable here
            Label1.Text = myDataTable.Rows[0]["item"].ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Also, please feel free to critique my existing code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public datatable mydatatable = new datatable(); //<------- THIS

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numPages = 3, numItems = 10;

        int[] parentRepeatCnt = Enumerable.Range(0, numPages).ToArray();
        int[] childRepeatCnt = Enumerable.Range(0, numItems).ToArray();

        ParentRepeater.DataSource = parentRepeatCnt;
        ParentRepeater.DataBind();

        foreach (int i in parentRepeatCnt)
        {
            Repeater ChildRepeater = ParentRepeater.Items[i].FindControl("ChildRepeater") as Repeater;
            ChildRepeater.DataSource = childRepeatCnt;
            ChildRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public void ChildRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            Label Label1 = e.Item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            // access DataTable here
            Label1.Text = myDataTable.Rows[0]["item"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare ur datatable as public above page load event ..that makes it accessible to all other funtions or methods in that page

Comment: If I'm filling it from a SQL Query, would do that in Page_Load, then?

Comment: Filling it in Page_Load seems to work, so unless someone suggests otherwise, I'll do it there. Thanks.